# Is there any way to quickly determine if a browser supports CORS-enabled images not tainting the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cors

Is there a quick test to determine if a browser supports CORS-enabled images not tainting a canvas when drawn on them.  I know Chrome 15 supports this, Firefox 9Beta but not Firefox 8, Safari doesn't, IE9 doesn't.  But there must be a pretty simple test to determine this, is basically drawing on a canvas with an image and seeing if you get an exception when you try to get image data, or is there any other easy way to determine this.

Comment: The method you described is probably easiest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I tested for CORS tained canvas support.  If someone has a way without having to load an image, please post it here:

```
function CanvasFunctions() {
    var _initialized = false, _corsNotSupported = false;


    function DrawImage(image, src) {
        jQuery.when(initialized()).then(function () { 
            if (_corsNotSupported) {
               image.src = GetProxyImage(src);
            } else {
               image.src = src;
            } 
        }
    }

    function initialized() {
        if (_initialized) {
            return true;
        }

        var dfd = $.Deferred();

        var src = 'http://example.com/corsImage.jpg',
            image.onload = function () {
                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = 250;
                canvas.height = 250;
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200);
                try {
                    var hit = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data[3] > 1;
                    console.log('Canvas was not tainted by CORS image, hit: ' + hit);
                } catch (e)  {
                    console.log('Canvas was tainted by CORS image, reverting to passthru for images');
                    _corsNotSupported = true;
                }
                _initialized = true;
                dfd.resolve(true);
            });

        image.src = src;


        return dfd.promise();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work:

```
if ('crossOrigin' in new Image())
    // ...
```

Comment: ```if ('crossOrigin' in document.createElement("img"))``` works too. Any idea if any browsers support this for ```video```?

Comment: But is this behavior defined in the W3 specs?

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to determine if a browser supports CORS is to look for the XHR's withCredentials property. IE uses the XDomainRequest object instead of XHR, so you need to look for that as well:

```
function supportsCors() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // Supports CORS
    return true;
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // IE
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Useful, but not what I was looking for.  This just tests to see if the browser supports CORS, not if it supports untained canvas from CORS images.

Comment: Are there any browsers that support one but not the other? I can't find untainted canvas listed on caniuse.com.

Comment: Safari (although I haven't checked 6 yet) still doesn't support untainted images in CORS.  I consider this a bug since Firefox and Chrome both fixed this over a year ago.