# Fastest way to check whether image (img HTML element) is not protected by CORS

Tags: javascript, cors

I occurred to have a problems when I copied image from a site (context menu->copy image) and pasted it in my script (in `contenteditable` div). `<img>` appears in the div, however an attempt to `drawImage` it on `<canvas>` will cause errors if you try to get image data of the canvas:

[image: Security error: the operation is insecure]

You **can draw on the canvas without errors**, but not retrieve the pixel data or DataURL. In cases of such images, I'd like to use [CORS proxy](http://www.corsproxy.com/) to have full access to the data.

How can  detect that I have no right to access data of `<img>` tag or `URL`? What's the fastest way?

I had this problem (and still have) in a [image paste upload script for StackExchange](https://stackapps.com/q/4999/28478).

**Edit:** Further explanations of the problem if you're still not sure what do I mean:

#### Why `try/catch` is not a solution?

You can draw any image on canvas and you can even perform further draw operations:

[image: CORS]

<sup>[The image source.](https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/black-religious-icons/40/Darth_Vader.png) It doesn't allow CORS!</sup>

#### Why parsing the URL doesn't help?

Some remote images allow CORS and do not throw any errors. For example the avatars from Gravatar.

Comment: domain, protocol and port must match, so you probably should check that the image URL matches the current domain, protocol and port.

Comment: @adeneo Some sites allow CORS. For example if I copy avatar in this post, it can be pasted (Gravatar allows cors).

Comment: @wwwmarty Error often occurs long after you retrieved image - it can be drawn on canvas, but ever since you draw it, canvas is blocked. That's the problem. Like poisonous apple.

Comment: Have you been through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image

Comment: @stackErr This is very interesting - it seems CORS is even less purposeful [than I thought](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/72207/23080). It's not an answer however - browser won't fill the attrubute for me - I need to **check**, and then perform some kind of action, not vice versa.

Comment: @TomášZato have a look at this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8438966/is-there-any-way-to-quickly-determine-if-a-browser-supports-cors-enabled-images

Comment: @TomášZato can you provide a jsFiddle with the problem you are having and include it in your question?

Comment: @stackErr The problem is described very well on the page you posted to - I need to *avoid tainting my canvas* by knowing that certain **specific** `<img>` is harmful. I'm working on the fiddle though already. For some reason, nobody seems to understand me... I don't really know what's unclear here.

Comment: @stackErr [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/2qa8b662/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the solution which actually *uses* `try ... catch` as [@wwwmarty suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27234695/607407#comment42946006_27234695). It's probably not very fast as of CPU speed and a little bit of a strange workaround, but it works:

```
HTMLImageElement.prototype.isTainting = function() {

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(this,0,0);
    try {
       canvas.toDataURL(); 
       return true;
    }
    catch(e) {return false;};
    return false;
}
```

I also created quite big [fiddle where you can inspect behavior of the `crossorigin` attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/Darker/2qa8b662/5/).

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing identifier in catch